cannot initialize proxy_sock map: update: socket operation on non-socket:
This is the main.go code. The code can be found on this repo: https://github.com/knrt10/proxify/tree/main
Commands used to compile the code:
# Build the proxify binary
make proxify

# To run in eBPF steering mode. Open up terminal and run the following.
sudo ./proxify -b


package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/knrt10/proxify/pkg/config"
    "github.com/knrt10/proxify/pkg/proxy"
    "github.com/knrt10/proxify/pkg/tracer"
)

var (
    lport = 8080
)

func main() {
    ctx := newCancelableContext()

    cfgStore := config.NewConfigStore("./config.json")

    // watch for changes to the config
    ch, err := cfgStore.StartWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer cfgStore.Close()

    go func() {
        for cfg := range ch {
            fmt.Println("got config change:", cfg)
        }
    }()

    // TODO: put a proxy here :)
    var bpfEnabled bool
    // flags declaration using flag package
    flag.BoolVar(&bpfEnabled, "b", false, "enable bpf steering")
    flag.IntVar(&lport, "p", 8080, "listener port for bpf steering")
    flag.Parse()

    // Load initial config from config.json file
    var cfg config.Config
    cfg, err = cfgStore.Read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var ports []int
    var targets []proxy.Target
    // Range through cfg to get port and target data
    for _, app := range cfg.Apps {
        for _, port := range app.Ports {
            var targets []proxy.Target
            ports = append(ports, port)
            // Create a new target instance for every target and append
            // it into a slice
            for _, target := range app.Targets {
                targets = append(targets, proxy.NewTargetServer(target))
            }
            // Create a new Loadbalancer for every port
            lb := proxy.NewLoadBalancer(port, targets)
            // Setup proxy as a different goroutine for every port
            go proxy.Setup(":"+strconv.Itoa(port), lb)
        }

        // These targets are used for port 8080 socket
        for _, target := range app.Targets {
            targets = append(targets, proxy.NewTargetServer(target))
        }
    }

    /* If ebpf steering is enabled then,
    Start the server on port 8080 for our proxify application.
    This socket pid will be used when updating BPF `proxy_sock` map.
    Server running on this port will redirect traffic to any given target
    that has the least traffic.
    */
    if bpfEnabled {
        go listen(targets)

        // HACK: Server is now already running on port 8080. This is done
        // to get the FD of the running socket
        cmd := exec.Command("lsof", "-i", ":"+strconv.Itoa(lport), "-FD")
        var out bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        pidFD := strings.Split(out.String(), "\n")
        fdString := strings.Split(pidFD[1], "f")[0]
        fd, _ := strconv.Atoi(fdString)

        // Start a new eBPF tracer
        t, err := tracer.NewTracer(ports)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        // Register the interface on every run
        if err := t.RegisterIface(0, fd); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
    <-ctx.Done()
}

// newCancelableContext returns a context that gets canceled by a SIGINT
func newCancelableContext() context.Context {
    doneCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(doneCh, os.Interrupt)

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    go func() {
        <-doneCh
        log.Println("signal recieved")
        cancel()
    }()

    return ctx
}

// listen is used to create a TCP server on a given port
func listen(targets []proxy.Target) {
    // Create a new Loadbalancer for port 8080
    lb := proxy.NewLoadBalancer(lport, targets)
    // Setup proxy as a different goroutine for every port
    proxy.Setup(":"+strconv.Itoa(lport), lb)
}

Here on this line I'm getting the error: fdString := strings.Split(pidFD[1], "f")[0] on line 99.
The error message is 2024/04/17 11:35:34 cannot initialize proxy_sock map: update: socket operation on non-socket:
How can I fix this error?

Could you share the full error message? I'm a bit surprised it happens on the strings.Split statement given the message looks more like something that would happen when you load the BPF program or create the BPF map.

This is the full error message I got

Ok... How do you know it's related to strings.Split?

Because before the code was fdString := strings.Split(pidFD[1], "f")[1]. which showed array index out of bounds. Then I changed it to fdString := strings.Split(pidFD[1], "f")[0] .Now I'm seeing this error.

Ok. So the previous issue was on that line and now the issue is somewhere else.

Then I'd recommend minimizing the code to pinpoint the issue. I doubt the bug is in the code you have shared here; it's more likely in tracer.NewTracer, t.RegisterIface, or wherever else you load the BPF program and its maps.
